# WCF client's and versioning

Tags: wcf, versioning

If I change the WCF, do I have to run some sort of update on all client computers that are accessing the service? (i.e. run svutils.exe and update all app.config's etc?)

Answer (score 9):

Read about data contact versioning:

[Data Contact Versioning:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138.aspx)

[Forward-Compatible Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx)

[Best Practices: Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Not unless the message changes and the change is required to use your service.

Answer (score 2):

If the signature of the WCF method does not change, then you will not need to update the clients. You can add new methods to the service if you need, instead of changing the signatures of existing methods.

Comment: true, but the only reason I would add new services would be for the clients to use!