# Boiler plate for WCF project, versioning anticipated

Tags: wcf, templates, versioning

I'm starting to find myself getting more and more in to using WCF for projects I implement for internal use (automating company tasks, making sure all clients are on the same page, etc.) This is largely due to the 3-10 clients I am automating at once whenever I do implement a solution, and (even if it was a small sample) the company is growing which continually adds more clients in the pool and thus a higher demand for reliability/consistency. With that said, I'm recognizing how important it is to make sure I make things expandable as (previously) pushing a release was getting harder the more clients I have depending on the service.

My latest project has a potential of being externalized. Until now I've done it the way I know works, but I'd still like to travel down the "right" path in terms of future updates. How should I be setting up my project file to make this as easy and seamless as possible to keep maintained, up-to-date and expansive? Should I be placing version numbers in to the namespace (as in Company.Interfaces.Contracts.June2011.IMyService), using pseudo folders, ...?

I just don't feel confident in this aspect of moving forward. I'd like to know that whatever ground work I have in place now won't place burdens on future expansion/customizing later. I'd also like to stick to the "development norm" as much as possible as it's getting more plausible that we'll hire additional programmers to help the work load.

Does anyone with this kind of experience have any thoughts, suggestions, guidance in this field? I would really appreciate any examples, books, documentation, etc. that you can provide.

---

#### Update (06-17-2011)

To give some insight, I'm also looking for some specific questions. These include:

1. How do you decorate a service class vs a DTO in terms of namespace? I've seen `http://service.domain.com/ServerName/Version` used on the Service class itself & `http://types.domain.com/ServiceName/Version` used on the DTOs. Is this common? (Separate the namespace in to a type and service collection?)
2. Should I be implementing `IExtensibleDataObject` on all my objects on the basis that they could potentially be evolved in future released? (Lay the ground work out now)
3. If my database has constraints on it for (e.g.) string length, I should be extending `IParameterInspector` and using that method for validity (keeping logic and validation separate), correct?
4. Should the "actual service" be broken out in to its own class so, as I version, the Service Contract classes just call the code (keeping each new version release with an minimal code as possible?) Or should I keep it within the service class and inherit from it with any new methods (likewise, what happens should you remove a method?)

I'm sorry if I have a lot of questions, I just see two ends of the spectrum in documentation. I see "Setting up wcf" then directly to "this is a versioned WCF"--no segue/steps between. I'm assuming it's going to just "click" once I get enough information, but I'm (sadly) not there yet.

---

**tl;dr**

When you start writing a WCF service that you know is going to hit several iterations, how do you setup your project(s) to make it as easy as possible in the future (on yourself and teammates)?

Comment: Anyone else want to chime in? I'd like to have a few options to go by here (and more so looking for examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had success using a "strict" versioning policy (it seems from past experience you are heading in this direction anyway) where you simply create new endpoint/s each time a new definition is released.  This means you won't have any contract backwards compatibility concerns for legacy clients - older versions can easily be turned off once logging indicates all clients have upgraded. It is generally necessary however to write bridging code for any legacy endpoint/s so they can continue to call into the modified business logic.

In terms of project organisation, I would create a new project for each version so they can easily be deployed separately.  Namespaces using v1, v2 are normally works well enough.  The endpoint names can also include a version number which should easily distinguish them from each other.

Alternately you could try using a "lax" versioning policy where you can have the ability to add or remove data members by implementing the IExtensibleDataObject interface in all your services. Some useful MSDN article links can be found in a popular response to a similar question: [WCF client's and versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225739/wcf-clients-and-versioning).

Another "lax" kind of option is to move more towards a messaging solution (which WCF can support through message contracts and/or the MSMQ binding). Here podcast by SOA guru Udi Dahan that provides an interesting perspective and is definitely worth a listen - [there is no IDog2](http://www.udidahan.com/2007/11/09/podcast-versioning-and-soa-there-is-no-idog2/).

Finally here is a good blog post with some further more fine-grained guidelines on whichever strategy you end up using:
   http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/wcf-versioning-guidelines-2/.

Comment: Interesting insight. In regards to a new project per version, you don't inherit interfaces/services and expand upon them, then expose the new contracts (in addition to keeping the older version, until a version runs extinct)? I also feel like the service should be a "dummy" class that calls my actual methods residing in another class making any new versions just a pointer to the service methods themselves--would you consider this "correct practice"? Though I understand WCF, versioning is still a bit of a black box (most likely due to me not having fully experiencing it yet).